# Append output to a file and redirect stderr to null

Tags: bash, io-redirection, stdout

How can I append the result of a command to a file and redirect stderr to null?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `>>` for appending and `2> /dev/null` for redirecting stderr:

`mycommand >> outputfile 2> /dev/null`

Although I suspect something very similar has been asked already...

Comment: I knew how to do each individually, but not both together. I couldn't find another question that asked for both.